# Finding the crash dump files for a C# app

Tags: c#, crash, memory-dump

An app I'm writing always crashes on a clients computer, but I don't get an exception description, or a stack trace.
The only thing I get is a crash report that windows wants to send to Microsoft.
I would like to get that dump file and investigate it myself, but I cannot find it.

When I "View the contents of the error report" I can see the different memory dumps, but I cannot copy it or save it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Windows debugging tools](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) to view the crash dump. To get the most use out of it, you'll need an exact copy of the symbols for that application (i.e. same version).

Have a look at [Tess's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) for tutorials on how to use the Windows debugging tools. I refer to her blog constantly whenever I'm in need of analysing crash dumps.

Comment: the link is dead now

Answer (score 6):

Tess' blog was a great resource. Eventually I managed to figure out how to do remote debugging which means I didn't have to look at the crash dump.

For the general community, here are some links I found useful:

- [Remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx), how to set up and run it.
- [Crash dumps](http://blogs.msdn.com/carloc/archive/2007/10/08/ok-now-how-do-i-capture-my-dump.aspx), how to save and debug them.